# Getting the physical location of extents of Mongodb indexes

Tags: mongodb

I've gone through the Mongodb docs trying to find a way to get the disk(physical) location of mongodb extents.
Well [presentation1](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/storage-engine-internals) and [presentation2](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongosf-2012-journaling-and-storage-engine) helped me to clear my fundamental basics of storage internals I got an idea of virtual mapping of address, but there was not much about how virtual to physical mapping is done in these presentations.

The diskLoc() method provides us the details for index file & offset. But there is no data about the extent number or its physical location.

```
db.system.indexes.find().showDiskLoc()
```

{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "*id*", "ns" : "mydb1.abc", "$diskLoc" : { "file" : 0, "offset" : 28848 } }

{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "x" : 1 }, "name" : "x_1", "ns" : "mydb1.abc", "$diskLoc" : { "file" : 0, "offset" : 28976 } }

{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "x" : 14 }, "name" : "x_14", "ns" : "mydb1.abc", "$diskLoc" : { "file" : 0, "offset" : 29104 } }

Can anyone help me to get the physical address of each index extent of file?

Comment: Pretty sure that the disk locations you are showing in your output are in fact the locations of the two documents that are present in the system.indexes collection for that database. That is, they do not represent the `diskLoc`s of the indexes themselves.  As far as I know, there is no way to do this for the MMAP engine without writing code and walking the extents.

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing the use case for this.

Comment: @AdamComerford you are correct diskloc provides only memory mapped addresses and not physical address.